# How to validate discord user ids?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a discord.py rewrite bot with a few moderation features such as ban, kick and as the problem is right now unban I need a way to validate that inputted discord ids are valid and not for example strings, too short too long.

Comment: What does a valid ID look like?

Answer (score 1):

Depending why you want to validate the input (I'm going to assume here that you just want trying to unban a user that doesn't exist to not raise an error), you can just call it anyway. Presumably the steps you are doing is somewhat like `get user` then `user unban` you can just use some `try-catch`es like the following:

```py
try:
    int_id = int(string_id)
    user = bot.fetch_user(int_id) # this should likely be async
    # whatever code you are already using here to link user id to a server
    # member or using the guild context route
except ValueError: # Python error if you cast a non-numeric string to int
    print(f"{string_id} is not a well-formed id.") # is not a number
except NotFound: #  # Discord error if there is no user for given id
    print(f"{int_id} is not a valid id.") # is a number but not a user
except HTTPException: # Discord error if could not contact server
    print(f"{int_id} could not be fetched.") # nothing to do with id
```

Comment: fetch_user is a coroutine, it should be awaited

Comment: As noted by the `# this should likely be async` comment, but it's hard to write a snippet that rightly needs to go ~around and through~ whatever code they are already using. Everything in `try` here should be treated as pseudocode for the existing approach.

Comment: If you don't `await` a coroutine it won't be called, it will return a `coroutine` object. To actually call and get the result we should `await` it.